# how to concatenate invoke-expression and variables in a one-liner

Tags: powershell, scriptblock

I want to set up a scheduled task and need to ideally fit the following in one line. I have tried using a script block `{}` but does not seem to work.

I want to try and put

```
[String] $cmd = Get-Content \pathto\script.ps1
Invoke-Expression $cmd
$othercmd = abc xyz
Invoke-Expression $othercmd
```

How would I go about joining them in a one liner so I coud call `powershell...`?

I know I could put it in a script and call that from schtasks but I am interested to see if there is a way to join the commands.

Comment: PowerShell statements can be daisy-chained by putting semicolons between the statements. With that said, since you want to run the statements as a scheduled task you should put them in a script anyway. And you [shouldn't be using `Invoke-Expression`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/) in the first place.